# Workflow Today function not working properly

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, date

i have written a small and simple workflow where in, i am capturing todays date when a status changes. 
The Column is of **Date Datatype(also tried with Single Line Data Type)**.
The workflow is running perfectly but the captured in the column is of yesterday and not the current date.

I have assigned todays date to a workflow variable, just an additional information.

Kindly help me through this, would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

This most likely happens as your server time is different from your timezone by x hours (unless it happens no matter the time of the day the workflow runs).

If that's the case simply add x hours to the date to get the correct one :)

Comment: i have configured my sub site time zone and thus it works correctly.